# Need to run python modules before importing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have three python files, named: Main.py, code1.py, code2.py. "Main.py" is calling the other two by "import code1" and "import code2" statements. code1 and code2 are receiving some numerical arrays, and returning some other numerical arrays by using function1 and function2, respectively.

Here is my problem: when I open main.py and run it, it says:

"name function1 is not defined"

Then, after running code1.py and code2.py, it works. After getting work done, I quit python. Next day, when I open and run main.py, same problem again.

Question: Why do I need to run code1.py and code2.py everytime before running main.py? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Note: I am using Python 3.6.1 on Anaconda 4.4.0 using Spyder 3.1.4

Comment: How do you run your python code?

Comment: Using the green run button on Spyder. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

On your code1.py and code2.py files, you should include a variable named `__all__ = ['function1']` and `__all__ = ['function2']` respectively. This is list contains tha names of the functions that are to be imported. When importing in Main.py, use: `from code1 import *` and same for code2.py and should work fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am very new to programming in Python. Now I understand that I need to use "from module_name import *".

Comment: Alternativly use `from module_name import function_name` so that you only need to look at the current file to determine where `function_name` comes from.